# How to solve javaDoc documentation warnings

Tags: java, javadoc

When I try to genereate javaDoc this warning is give it to me, what is the possible problem i cant solve it. i have my documentation like the following example:

```
/**
* @param maxC - tamanho maximo do salto do Cacador
* @param posC - a posicao atual do cacador
* @param posS - a posicao atual do Smutchi
* @param maxS - tamanho maximo do salto do Smutchi
* @param dim - dimensao do tabuleiro
*
* @return - O salto que o Cacador deve dar se o Smutchi estiver ah esquerda do
*           cacador
*
* @requires - posC != posS
* @requires - posS > 0 e posS <= dim e posC > 0 e posC <= dim e maxS > 0 e 
*             maxC > 0 e dim > 0 
*/
```

Note: Custom tags that could override future standard tags:  @requires. To avoid potential overrides, use at least one period character (.) in custom tag names.
1 warning